# How can I process JSON data in JQuery, that's being returned with a header type of "text/html"?

Tags: jquery, html, json, getjson

I'm trying to use the jquery, `getJSON` method to get JSON data from a public API.  I keep getting the following errors when the callback of my `getJSON` request executes.

> **Warning:** Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html
>
> **Error:** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I've inspected the header of the response and, sure enough, it is set to `text\html`.  Since this is a public API that I can't control, how can I easily request and parse this JSON data?

For reference, the link below is the link to the JSON data that I am trying to acquire.

JSON Request (http://bitcoincharts.com/t/weighted_prices.json)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't control the mime type, use `jQuery.ajax` instead of `jQuery.getJSON`. Then in the success callback you can do something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "text", //you may need this.
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        ....
    }
});
```

Another thing you could try is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //data here will be a JavaScript object
        ....
    }
});
```

Although I'm not sure if jQuery will complain if the mime type doesn't match. It's worth a shot though.

**EDIT:** On another note, how are you able to access that data from your script? Even though it's a public API, it's on another server and so that will violate the same-origin policy. When I do the following:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://bitcoincharts.com/t/weighted_prices.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

From my Chrome console, I see the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bitcoincharts.com/t/weighted_prices.json?_=1346263039525. Origin http://stackoverflow.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

You have to see if BitCoin Charts supports a JSONP alternative. Otherwise, your only option is to set up something on the server-side that grabs this data for you and returns it back to you in JSON with the correct mime-type.

Comment: Is the `JSON` object part of jquery? (I must admit, I'm a JQuery newb.)

Comment: `JSON` should be available from the browser. All modern browsers should support it; it doesn't come from jQuery.

Comment: Regarding your `JSONP` comment.  I'm seeing a request/response in Firebug from within Chrome.  I assume it's working, though it's hard to verify with these error messages.  Would you mind posting a sample alternative?  I've had minimal HTML/Javascript experience over the years and, to be honest, this is the first AJAXy type requirement that I've had, from within the browser.  I can parse and consume this stuff all day in C#, Obj-C and Python... but this is a first for me with the browser.