# Why are html tags being returned with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Why are html tags appearing in my input box along with the variable I need.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function(event){ // use instead of onclick()
            event.preventDefault(); // prevents the default click action
            $.get('find_email.php', function(session) {
                 $('#id1').val( session); // session data will be 'foo'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="find_email.php">click</a>
<div><input id="id1" value=""></div>
</body>
```

php file, find_email.php:

```
<?php
$var = $_SESSION['user_id']; 
echo $var;
?>
```

Result displayed in the input box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"> 41
```

All I want is the 41 appearing in the box or assigned to variable.

Research:

- [After being returned by my factory service, data is displaying with visible HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760192/after-being-returned-by-my-factory-service-data-is-displaying-with-visible-html)
- [How can I process JSON data in JQuery, that's being returned with a header type of "text/html"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183402/how-can-i-process-json-data-in-jquery-thats-being-returned-with-a-header-type)
- [How to use jQuery variable into html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682573/how-to-use-jquery-variable-into-html)

Comment: Something else not shown is outputting the html at server. Are you using a php framework?

Comment: Can you console.log the session variable in your javascript ?

Comment: @SofieneDjebali what would that show that would be any different than putting it into a form control as value?

Comment: No php framework being used. I am using two other lines of code: require_once ('includes/config.inc.php'); and include ('includes/header.html'); they only start the session and store some other database settings. My goal is to transfer the php $var (holding a user_id) to a javascript var in a different file. The input box is not essential and I only came across it here in research. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455590/how-to-read-a-session-variable-from-a-php-file-in-javascript as a method to try. Thank you

Comment: I searched the header.html file and found a line of code similar to the extra going into the input box. Deleted and now this is working. Thank you charlietfl. How can I give you credit.